# Create list of certain size in Java from SortedSet

Tags: java, performance, collections, guava

I've a `SortedSet` of `TreeSet` implementation, which I often convert to list via `new ArrayList<>(mySortedSet)` and then do `subList(myList, 3)` or any other number of elements.

How can I avoid using the `subList` on the new list creating and only get the `ArrayList` of required elements from `SortedSet` in one go.
Using Java 11 with Guava.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Java only:

```
List<E> list = sortedSet.stream().limit(3).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  Adding an external dependency for something so fundamental is not a good practice.

Answer (score 3):

```
ImmutableList.copyOf(Iterables.limit(sortedSet, 3));
```

That should be all you need -- `Iterables.limit` does the important part.

Answer (score 1):

For three smallest elements you could use

```
Iterator<E> it = mySortedSet.iterator();
ArrayList<E> = Lists.newArrayList(it.next(), it.next(), it.next());
```

This looks pretty hacky as it depends on the evaluation order of the arguments (which is guaranteed in Java). It also blows when the set is smaller. I'm not really recommending it as I wrote it, but you get the idea.

However, when all you need is these three elements, you can use a `PriorityQueue` or Guava's `Comparators.least(int, Comparator)`.